# Multi Set as a class template using list functions as basis

Tags: c++, list, class, templates, set

The basis of the program is a header file that defines the template class miniMultiSet. The class uses the list structure as the implementation structure for the multiset. The class is implemented in the header file by implementing the defined class methods.

When I do this I am running into issues sending the information from main.cpp to my header file.  There are not error messages, it just freezes and I have to close it.  This makes me think I have an error in my memory management.

HEADER FILE:

```
#ifndef MINIMULTISET_H_INCLUDED
#define MINIMULTISET_H_INCLUDED

#include <list>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class miniMultiSet
{
    public:

    typedef typename list<T>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename list<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    // miniMultiSet iterators are simply list iterators

    miniMultiSet();
    // default constructor

    bool empty() const{return l.empty();}
    // is the multiset empty?

    int size() const{return l.size();}
    // return the number of elements in the multiset


    iterator insert(const T& item)
    {
        l.insert(l.end(), item);
        return l.end();
    }
    // insert item into multi set and return an
    // iterator pointing at the new element.


    private:
    list<T> l;
    // multiset implemented using a list
};


#endif // MINIMULTISET_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp //////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

#include "miniMultiSet.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    miniMultiSet<int> *A;
    A=0;

    *A->insert(90);

    cout << A->size() << endl;

    if(A->empty())
        cout << "Set is empty." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Set contains data." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I build it and there are no error statements.  When I run it I get "Program has stopped working, searching for a solution.".  It then ends the program and I get "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) execution time: 4.421 s.  Press any key to continue."

I am not sure how to fix this, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `A` is a null pointer.  There's no obvious reason here for `A` to be a pointer in the first place.

Comment: I didn't initially try A as a pointer, but miniMultSet<int> A is used and dot for the functions I get "undefined reference to miniMultSet<int>::miniMultiSet()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot ever construct a `miniMultiSet` because you declared its default constructor but never defined it.  It seems like you should simply remove your default constructor declaration, as the compiler-generated one will work fine, and then do `miniMultiSet<int> A` without a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The code above altered to make a multiset operate like a list.

HEADER FILE:

```js
#ifndef MINIMULTISET_H_INCLUDED
#define MINIMULTISET_H_INCLUDED

#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class miniMultiSet
{
     public:

 typedef typename list<T>::iterator iterator;
 typedef typename list<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;
 // miniMultiSet iterators are simply list iterators

 //miniMultiSet();
 // default constructor

 bool empty() const{return l.empty();}
 // is the multiset empty?

 int size() const{return l.size();}
 // return the number of elements in the multiset

 int count (const T& item)
 {
     int tally = 0;
     std::list<int>::iterator is;
     for(is=l.begin();is!=l.end();++is)
        {
            if(*is==item)
                tally++;
        }
        return tally;
 }
 // return the number of duplicate occurrences of item
 // in the multiset


 iterator find (const T& item)
 {
      std::list<int>::iterator it;
      for(it=l.begin();it!=l.end();++it)
         {
             if(*it==item)
                break;
         }
         return it;
 }
 // search for item in the multiset and return an iterator
 // pointing at the first occurrence matching item, or end()
 // if it is not found


 const_iterator find (const T& item) const
 {
      int count=0;
      std::list<int>::iterator it;
      for(it=l.begin();it!=l.end();++it)
         {
             if(*it==item)
                break;
         }
 }
 // constant version

 
 iterator insert(const T& item)
 {
     l.insert(l.end(), item);
     return l.end();
    }
 // insert item into multi set and return an
 // iterator pointing at the new element.

 int erase(const T& item)
 {
      int count=0;
      std::list<int>::iterator it;
      std::list<int>::iterator il;
      for(it=l.begin();it!=l.end();++it)
         {
             if(*it==item)
             {
                it=l.erase((it));
                it--;
                ++count;
             }

         }
         return count;
 }
 // erase all occurrences of item from the multi set
 // and return the number of items erased.

 iterator begin(){return l.begin();}
 // return an iterator pointing at the first member
 // in the multiset

 const_iterator begin() const{return l.cbegin();}
 // constant version

 iterator end(){return l.end();}
 // return an iterator pointing just past the last
 // member in the muktiset

 const_iterator end() const{return l.cend();}
 // constant version


    private:
 list<T> l;
 // multiset implemented using a list
};


#endif // MINIMULTISET_H_INCLUDED
```

MAIN CPP FILE

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

#include "miniMultiSet.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    miniMultiSet<int> A;

    A.insert(80);
    A.insert(90);
    A.insert(90);
    A.insert(90);
    A.insert(95);
    A.insert(100);
    A.insert(105);
    A.insert(110);
    A.insert(115);
    A.insert(120);

    if(A.empty())
            cout << "Set is empty." << endl;
        else
            cout << "Set is NOT empty." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "This size of the Multi Set is: " << A.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The first element is: " << *A.begin() << endl;
    if(A.find(90)!=A.end())
        cout << "90 was found" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "90 was found " << A.count(90) << " times." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //pair<int, int>(90);

    cout << "90 was found " << A.erase(90) << " times and erased." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "This size of the Multi Set is: " << A.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "90 was found " << A.count(90) << " times." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Not the prettiest or most efficient, but it works.  Thank you for all the help.